# Royal Mail CMDM Barcode

Tags: zpl

I am using BarTender to design a set of labels to print to ZPL printers. One of my requirements is for a Royal Mail Mailmark label which uses the CMDM Barcode.
We output to file using alias values in the label fields.
We then run an application which swaps out the alias values and replaces them with the database values we actually want to print.
The issue is when I open label designs previously used to create the template files, the output (which previously was in simple text form) has now been outputted into a DGR....GRF format. (Please see below)
Unfortunately the CMDM barcode on BarTender is designed so that I can't just use an alias. That is my understanding anyway.

```
^FT407,1137

^A0B,28,34^FD*ship_to_zip^FS

^FT659,1148

^A0B,25,31^FDOur Reference ^FS

^FT564,1148

^A0B,25,28^FDCustomer Reference^FS

^FT595,1148

^A0B,25,28^FD*po_nbr^FS

^FT697,1148

^A0B,25,28^FD*distro_nbr^FS

^FO553,300

^BY2^BCB,124,N,N^FD>:*carton_nbr^FS

^FO28,72

^XGR:SSGFX000.GRF,1,1^FS

^ISR:SS_TEMP.GRF,N^XZ
~DGR:SSGFX001.GRF,1352,13,:Z64:eJydk9ERBCEMQtMB/XdJBxzE3D93ruP6nDHBoMDvjYBEDoZqYeSF8TiCSqC7vD2IEvK5Z3cNTkRqZ2phnM4zKyZbSIic0YprcIAMLrpqUHQSV8UOUo/dij1dBTGXCaT1oAIrdEp6Kbeig/jlCCZNC7H3Sk6U4ADMEV3+TdrAXoxLjRL4HoUjjFqIOM+2/i2k7PEY++/A+fTd2cKz+ElVCTN7XVdqC/b1pK4FFeRlnNT3agv4p30AH1GDtw==:D4A2

^XA

^ILR:SS_TEMP.GRF^FS

^FO242,308

^XGR:SSGFX001.GRF,1,1^FS

^PQ1,0,1,Y
^XZ
```

Has anyone come across this problem or know of a ZPL command I can use for this type of Barcode?
The main issue is Royal Mail want the Latch to C40 at the beginning of the barcode. When I print a standard 2D DataMatrix barcode, this latch to C40 code appears in the middle of the code.
Just need to know if I can move it to the beginning of the code.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The ZPL datamatrix command does not support manually encoding the code words, which is what you need to force a latch to C40.  But you can use BarTender to get around this. (I am not associated with Seagull Scientific, but my clients often use it.)

Instead of programmatically modifying the BT format file directly, you should be generating a data file that provides the field data for the label.  BarTender calls this "data file integration".

See this video for more information: https://support.seagullscientific.com/hc/en-us/articles/227353867-Print-Document-Using-a-Data-File-Integration-Video-6-31-